Binding list to CollectionView crashes app in Release mode but not Debug
In my MAUI app I have a CollectionView that I'm binding to a list generated from a SQLite Database. It works perfectly fine when debugging, but if I try to set the build to release then the app crashes when it gets to this point.
Here's the XAML code for the CollectionView:
<CollectionView x:Name="listCUs" Grid.Row="1"
    Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }" SelectionChanged="listCUs_SelectionChanged"
    ItemsSource="{ Binding Items }"   SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OnItemSelected}" 
SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference listCUs}}"
    SelectedItem="{ Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay }" SelectionMode="Single" >

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:NavigationCardsListItemTemplate HeightRequest="{ OnIdiom Phone=100, Tablet=120 }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

Here is the code that binds the CollectionView:
protected override void OnAppearing()
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cuSearch.Text))
    {
        LoadList();
    }
    else
    {
        FilterList();
    }
}

public void LoadList()
{
    using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {
        var cus = conn.Table<tblCredit_Union>().ToList();
        listCUs.ItemsSource = cus;
    }
}

Here is the crash log from my phone:
    -------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 8E291CF4-057E-4B01-A6BC-1FB5416B4FC3
CrashReporter Key:   5b2554a02654b205a877ee758efdca8f3ec3cffe
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,3
Process:             ASIMobile [5087]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2299CD36-ECE4-4F1C-B272-20F1034A75C1/ASIMobile.app/ASIMobile
Identifier:          com.americanshare.ASIMobile4
Version:             4.0.2 (1.8)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.americanshare.ASIMobile4 [1272]

Date/Time:           2024-07-19 10:45:55.3306 -0400
Launch Time:         2024-07-19 10:44:23.2422 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.5.1 (21F90)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.50.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: ASIMobile [5087]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 name:  tid_103 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2f42c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cec0c pthread_kill + 267
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x19a8d2ba0 abort + 179
3   ASIMobile                              0x10aa90da0 0x1044fc000 + 106515872
4   ASIMobile                              0x10a9ed9e8 0x1044fc000 + 105847272
5   libsystem_platform.dylib               0x1ef712e9c _sigtramp + 55
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cec0c pthread_kill + 267
7   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x19a8d2ba0 abort + 179
8   ASIMobile                              0x10a6cfa68 0x1044fc000 + 102578792
9   ASIMobile                              0x10a923de4 0x1044fc000 + 105020900
10  ASIMobile                              0x10a9c3c2c 0x1044fc000 + 105675820
11  ASIMobile                              0x10a6d808c 0x1044fc000 + 102613132
12  ASIMobile                              0x10aa2caec 0x1044fc000 + 106105580
13  dyld                                   0x1b5ff5e4c start + 2239

Thread 1 name:  SGen worker
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2a1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7ca6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1227
2   ASIMobile                              0x10a8fe1f0 0x1044fc000 + 104866288
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 2 name:  Finalizer
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba24784 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   ASIMobile                              0x10a99e610 0x1044fc000 + 105522704
2   ASIMobile                              0x10a97b02c 0x1044fc000 + 105377836
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba24808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba28008 mach_msg2_internal + 79
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba27f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 435
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba27d60 mach_msg + 23
4   CoreFoundation                         0x192944f5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 159
5   CoreFoundation                         0x192944600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1207
6   CoreFoundation                         0x192943cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 607
7   Foundation                             0x191864e4c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 211
8   Foundation                             0x191864c9c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 63
9   UIKitCore                              0x194f90640 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 419
10  Foundation                             0x19187b718 __NSThread__start__ + 731
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 4 name:  .NET Timer
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2a1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7ca6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1227
2   ASIMobile                              0x1052c20a4 0x1044fc000 + 14442660
3   ASIMobile                              0x10a3a98b0 0x1044fc000 + 99276976
4   ASIMobile                              0x10a9be788 0x1044fc000 + 105654152
5   ASIMobile                              0x10a965de8 0x1044fc000 + 105291240
6   ASIMobile                              0x10a97b124 0x1044fc000 + 105378084
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 5 name:  .NET TP Gate
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2a1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7ca710 _pthread_cond_wait + 1271
2   ASIMobile                              0x10a73a640 SystemNative_LowLevelMonitor_TimedWait + 104
3   ASIMobile                              0x1052c38ac 0x1044fc000 + 14448812
4   ASIMobile                              0x10a2074f8 0x1044fc000 + 97563896
5   ASIMobile                              0x10a39db64 0x1044fc000 + 99228516
6   ASIMobile                              0x10a9be788 0x1044fc000 + 105654152
7   ASIMobile                              0x10a965de8 0x1044fc000 + 105291240
8   ASIMobile                              0x10a97b124 0x1044fc000 + 105378084
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 6 name:  tid_8313
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80c4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13 name:  .NET TP Worker
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2a1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7ca6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1227
2   ASIMobile                              0x10a8afb50 0x1044fc000 + 104545104
3   ASIMobile                              0x10a8b3c70 0x1044fc000 + 104561776
4   ASIMobile                              0x1050fac00 0x1044fc000 + 12577792
5   ASIMobile                              0x10a39fc54 0x1044fc000 + 99236948
6   ASIMobile                              0x10a9be788 0x1044fc000 + 105654152
7   ASIMobile                              0x10a965de8 0x1044fc000 + 105291240
8   ASIMobile                              0x10a97b124 0x1044fc000 + 105378084
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7

Thread 14 name:  .NET TP Worker
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dba2a1cc __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7ca6e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1227
2   ASIMobile                              0x10a8afb50 0x1044fc000 + 104545104
3   ASIMobile                              0x10a8b3c70 0x1044fc000 + 104561776
4   ASIMobile                              0x1050fac00 0x1044fc000 + 12577792
5   ASIMobile                              0x10a39fc54 0x1044fc000 + 99236948
6   ASIMobile                              0x10a9be788 0x1044fc000 + 105654152
7   ASIMobile                              0x10a965de8 0x1044fc000 + 105291240
8   ASIMobile                              0x10a97b124 0x1044fc000 + 105378084
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7cd06c _pthread_start + 135
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ef7c80d8 thread_start + 7


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0xffffffff9f6ef219   x5: 0x0000000000000018   x6: 0x000000016b902d70   x7: 0x000000016b902460
    x8: 0xf21e1e4d4e157568   x9: 0xf21e1e4cbd73cba8  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016b9024d0
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000104de99a0  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001f366bec0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x00000001f366bfa0  x22: 0x000000010d93e200  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000303f8e490  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x000000016b903c77
   x28: 0x00000003029845a0   fp: 0x000000016b902d80   lr: 0x00000001ef7cec0c
    sp: 0x000000016b902d60   pc: 0x00000001dba2f42c cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x112a50000 -        0x112a5bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <2e2c05f8377a30899ad91926d284dd03> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x10c250000 -        0x10c383fff libHarfBuzzSharp arm64  <9963a21c847c33409c756a1056a8a6b3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2299CD36-ECE4-4F1C-B272-20F1034A75C1/ASIMobile.app/Frameworks/libHarfBuzzSharp.framework/libHarfBuzzSharp
       0x10c95c000 -        0x10cebffff libSkiaSharp arm64  <649ef09dce4e3167a06b4c7ae3801717> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2299CD36-ECE4-4F1C-B272-20F1034A75C1/ASIMobile.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp
       0x1044fc000 -        0x10b00bfff ASIMobile arm64  <150884d1c9a439b0ad3a82dcaf34fd53> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2299CD36-ECE4-4F1C-B272-20F1034A75C1/ASIMobile.app/ASIMobile
       0x1dba23000 -        0x1dba5cfef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <13b5134e819c3baab3004856112114cb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1ef7c7000 -        0x1ef7d3ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <1196b6c3333d3450818ff3663484b8eb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x19a85d000 -        0x19a8daff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <b122f07fa15637f3a22d64627c0c4b24> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x1ef712000 -        0x1ef718ff3 libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <e99607c14f1330b7bd1543c363b459c8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x1b5fb9000 -        0x1b6045ef7 dyld arm64e  <71846eacee653697bf7d790b6a07dcdb> /usr/lib/dyld
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???
       0x1928f1000 -        0x192e1efff CoreFoundation arm64e  <00e76a98210c3cb5930bf236807ff24c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x19179d000 -        0x192312fff Foundation arm64e  <3d3a12e3f5e9361fb00a4a5e8861aa55> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x194b72000 -        0x196692fff UIKitCore arm64e  <1741fa374e53371e8daed611aab0043d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore

EOF

What could be causing this?
UPDATE:
I have narrowed it down to being due to a CircleCachedImage control within the NavigationCardsListItemTemplate.
The markup releven within the NavigationCardsListItemTemplate this template:
<local:CircleCachedImage
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Source="{Binding Avatar}"
    Style="{ StaticResource Avatar}"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

The class for the CircleCachedImage:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using FFImageLoading.Maui;
using FFImageLoading.Transformations;
using FFImageLoading.Work;
using UXDivers.Grial;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui;

namespace ASIMobile
{
    public class CircleCachedImage : CachedImage
    {
        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BorderColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(CircleCachedImage),
                defaultValue: Colors.Transparent,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                propertyChanged: OnBorderColorChanged);

        public static BindableProperty BorderSizeProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BorderSize),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(CircleCachedImage),
                defaultValue: 1.0,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                propertyChanged: OnBorderSizeChanged);

        private readonly CircleTransformation _transformation;

        public CircleCachedImage()
        {
            _transformation = new CircleTransformation(BorderSize * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density, BorderColor.ToHex());

            base.Transformations.Add(_transformation);
        }

        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public new List<ITransformation> Transformations
        {
            get => throw new NotSupportedException();
            set => throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public double BorderSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BorderSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnBorderColorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (view is CircleCachedImage cacheImage && cacheImage._transformation != null)
            {
                cacheImage._transformation.BorderHexColor = cacheImage.BorderColor.ToHex();
            }
        }

        private static void OnBorderSizeChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (view is CircleCachedImage cacheImage && cacheImage._transformation != null)
            {
                cacheImage._transformation.BorderSize = cacheImage.BorderSize * DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
            }
        }
    }
}


attach a debugger and find out?

@ClausJørgensen the issue does not occur when I debug

Because by default you'll be debugging a debug build. You can still attach a debugger to a release build

Or add some basic exception handling and logging .  Or use a crash reporting tool

When you are getting an exception and you decide to use SO, Always remember two thing, Error message and StackTrace are a must!

@FreakyAli A lot of my issue here is that I am having trouble figuring out how to even go about debugging this.
I have attached the crash logs from my phone if they help, to me they are incomprehensible and seem to imply the error is happening at the kernel?

@Jason I have updated my post with a crash report log

That’s not what I suggested.  YOU need to add exception handling and logging to YOUR code.  And/or use a tool like Sentry or Raygun to capture the crash

@Jason as I mentioned a lot of my problem with this is the difficulty of debugging. I can check out Sentry and Raygun but are they going to actually provide more info than the apple crash log?
I have determined the crash does not happen on any particular line of my code, it appears when trying to actually render the CollectionView. It does not crash if I comment out the code setting the source of the CollectionView, but there is no exception that occurs there.

Try replacing your template with a simple Label

@Jason Thank you, that worked and helped narrow it down a lot as I found it was due to a CircleCachedImage control that may no longer work well with MAUI. Still troubleshooting more on how to fix it.

Still troubleshooting more on how to fix it.  Hi @rgorr, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets (e.g. NavigationCardsListItemTemplate and the view model of current page) so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

@JessieZhang-MSFT certainly, I have updated the post with more details on the template. The post should already contain the detail needed from the view model, but if there is anything I missed that you need let me know.

Sorry, I couldn't find code NavigationCardsListItemTemplate from your post.

@JessieZhang-MSFT you can use the markup included for local:CircleCachedImage in its place to replicate the issue
